# How to set rounding precision for GiB (etc.)

Tags: gui, settings

When I copy files in GUI app I could see up to 5 digits for example `1,002.3 MiB -> 1,002.4 MiB etc` but then displaying step is changed radically to `1.0 Gib -> 1.1 Gib`.

It seems to be system setting because more GUI apps has this behavior.

Is it possible to change it? For example to show `1.001 GiB -> 1.002 GiB` etc.?